# How can I delete one particular line which consist certain string in python without creating new file?

Tags: python

So basically I have this one particular problem where I have to apply all the CRUD operations on one TEXT file using python. I did complete create, read orations and I did Delete part as well but with 2 different text files (ie Source file and Target File). Now, My question is **Can we delete one particular line which consist certain string without creating new file (with Existing source file) in python?**

employee.txt
**Harsh Patel 20.0 60.0
Peter Piper 15.5 40.0 
Manish Mannon 27.5 38.5 
Luke Papa 25 50**

This is my text file. Now I am asking from user that which employee data line you want to remove. Then User will input **Harsh Patel**. 
I want to delete whole line which contains Harsh Patel.

PS: I am new to Python and Experimenting stuff with File Processing.

**EDIT:**
So meanwhile I came up with other solution. But the main problem is it writes the last line of my text file again.

```
with open('employee.txt') as f,open('employee.txt','w') as f2:
    for x in f:
        if 'Harsh Patel' not in x:
            f2.write(x)
```

So the output of this is,
**1st line** Peter Piper 15.5 40.0 
**2nd line** Manish Mannon 27.5 38.5 
**3rd line** Luke Papa 25 50
**4th line** Luke Papa 25 50

4th line is duplicate of 3rd line.

Comment: you can, if the file is not huge, read the file into memory and then overwrite the appropriate lines back to the file. If the file size is greater than your RAM then you will likely have a `MemoryError`

Comment: Can you please provide what code you have tried so far and the issues you have had as that is the purpose of this website.

Comment: also you can use bash `sed` command, I think Is better solution, and If you still want to use inside python you can use the `subprocess` module to run `sed` from the python script

Comment: @Professor_Joykill you just killed the joy :)

Comment: @AGNGazer Hey it's my job

Comment: @HarshPatel How do you know which line to delete?

Comment: @AGNGazer Suppose I have one line in text file,
**Harsh Patel 20.0 10.0**
I want to delete this whole line by giving input as 
**Harsh Patel**

Comment: my script works :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your text file is separated with '\n' so you can use this:

```
THE_LINE = "Harsh Patel"
file = open("filename.txt", "r")
# read the text as a list of lines:
text = file.readlines()
file.close()
# use filter, to filter elements from a list, use lambda to create a mini function:
new_text = filter(lambda element: THE_LINE not in element, text)
file = open("filename.txt", "w")
# use join to make a string out of a list in the format you choose, the string there is empty because we have the '\n' in the list already:
file.write("".join(new_text))
file.close()
```

to recheck your code you can use this code which will rewrite to file:

```
a = "Harsh Patel 20.0 60.0\nPeter Piper 15.5 40.0\nManish Mannon 27.5 38.5\nLuke Papa 25 50"
file = open("filename.txt", "w")
file.write(a)
file.close()
```

Comment: meanwhile I came up with another solution. But, I don't know why it is writing the last line of my text file again in text file. see my answer.

Comment: @HarshPatel I don't know why your answer not working, I guess that because f is a file pointer, so you can't really do x in f, but did so... maybe you didn't closed the files? please write all of your script, so I will be able to  see exactly what is the problem

Answer (score 0):

Well if you know the line I guess you can try this:

```
THE_LINE = "......."
file = open("filename.txt", "r")
text = file.read()
file.close()
# to delete, replace the line with nothing:
text = text.replace(THE_LINE, "")
file = open("filename.txt", "w")
file.write(text)
file.close()
```

hope that was helpful.

Comment: This creates a *new* file

Comment: In a way... it overwrite the previous file, so no new file is created.

Comment: I know the name. see,
**Harsh Patel 20.0 60.0 
Peter Piper 15.5 40.0 
Manish Mannon 27.5 38.5
Luke Papa 25 50**
This is my text file.
Now I am asking from user that which employee data line you want to remove. Then User will input **Harsh Patel**. 
I want to delete whole line which contains **Harsh Patel**.

PS: I am new to Python and Experimenting stuff with File Processing in python.

Comment: You can separate the file with '\n' as:  "Harsh Patel 20.0 60.0\nPeter Piper 15.5 40.0\nManish Mannon 27.5 38.5\nLuke Papa 25 50"
and then use readlines() function to get a list of the lines, and then delete from the list the element which in the name that the user entered, I will write another answer that show how you can do that.

Comment: @messy212
I do have text file line 1st line **Harsh Patel 20.0 60.0**
2nd line **Peter Piper 15.5 40.0** so on.

So when I am using f.read() then it is giving the same which mentioned in your first line.

Comment: I just posted another answer, try it. tell me how it went.

Comment: @messy212 Smooth it was. Thank you man. 
Now same way I can work on Update string as well on same text file. 
The other objective is to update string in the same txt file. Which i am trying to do now.

Answer (score 0):

Using sed

```
import subprocess
THE_FILE = 'file.txt'
THE_LINE = 'line to delete'
sub = subprocess.call(['sed','-i', '/'+THE_LINE+'/d', THE_FILE  ])
```